# return Changed arrayList from adapter android

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

have gridview for which set adapter called ImageAdapter with parameter of arraylist. Inside the adapter have onclicklistener during which from the arraylist one item is removed and then when i use this line `ImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in the gridview item is removed. Now i need the changed arrayList in my activity so how can i get it.

Here's my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> listCheck = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ImageAdapter adapter = this;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) { 
    this.context = context; 
    listCheck = list; 
}    
    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return listCheck.size();
}

    @Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null; 
}

    @Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

    @Override 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder121 holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(         
        R.layout.item_gridmain, null);  
        holder = new ViewHolder121();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_selected_image); 
       holder.close = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_btn_cancel); 
        convertView.setTag(holder);     
}

        else { 
        holder = (ViewHolder121) convertView.getTag();
    } 
    holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(View arg1) {
                listCheck.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }  
}); Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(listCheck.get(position), 220,
                220);   
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);    
        return convertView; 
}       }
```

Fragment code:

```
ImageAdapter mainActivityAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), ar1);    
                 gridview_withimage.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);
```

question: How to get changed arraylist from ImageAdapter to called Fragement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to get changed arraylist from ImageAdapter to called Fragement

Create a method in `ImageAdapter` which will return ArrayList used as data-source in Adapter:

```
public ArrayList<String> getModifyList() {
    return listCheck; 
}
```

Call `getModifyList` method in Fragment for getting ArrayList using Adapter object:

```
gridview_withimage.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);
gridview_withimage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

 @Override
  public void run() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> arrNewList=mainActivityAdapter.getModifyList();           
  }
 }, 100);
```

Comment: i have tried this but i want this function to return arraylist onclick of clear button

Comment: holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(View arg1) {
                listCheck.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }  
});

Comment: once close button is clicked then listCheck<arrayList> value is removed from corresponding position then how to get this changed listCheck <arrayList> to my fragment?

Comment: @Anitha: when you want to get changed listCheck <arrayList> values in fragment?

Comment: once setAdapter is called i need the changed arrayList

Comment: @Anitha: if you are using `gridview_withimage.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);` line in `onCreate` method of Activity or Fragment. then use `ArrayList<String> arrNewList=mainActivityAdapter.getModifyList();` in `onResume()`

Comment: i am calling setAdapter method inside onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Fragment instance to Adapter.

```
private Fragment fragment;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list,Fragment mfragment) { 
    this.context = context; 
    listCheck = list; 
    this.fragment=mfragment;
}
```

and Make one public method in your fragment and call using this instance of Fragment fragment;

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface like this

```
public interface ImageAdapterListener{
    void onListChange(List<String> list);
}
```

And declare a member in `ImageAdapter`

```
private ImageAdapterListener listener;

public setListener(ImageAdapterListener listener){
this.listener = listener}
```

override the notifyDataSetChanged

```
@Override
void notifyDataSetChanged{
super.notifyDataSetChanged();
if(listener!= null) listener.onListChange(listCheck);
}
```

and make your fragment implement that interface.

```
class Myfragment extends Fragment implements ImageAdapterListener {
ImageAdapter mainActivityAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), ar1);    
                 gridview_withimage.setAdapter(mainActivityAdapter);
mainActivityAdapter.setListener(this);

@Override 
void onListChange(List<String> list){
//do your stuff
}
    }
```

Comment: Though it looks safe and simple, will it pass a list on every change of data in adapter?

Comment: If you always call notifyDataSetChanged after updating the data then yes, otherwise no. This is an old answer though, I suggest that you should checkout recyclerview adapter's notify methods

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar solution with interface, but without notifyDataSetChanged, just on button click.